# Dropdown menu horizontal instead of vertical

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to figure out how to fix this drop-down menu. It seems to look okay until I hover and the menu appears horizontal instead of vertical. Is it something wrong with the css?

Thanks for your help!

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TcGQz/)

HTML

```
<body> 
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>
<nav id="mainnav"><img src="../images/Website/banner.jpg" width="1280" height="120">
 <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="../research.htm">Research</a></li>
      <li><a href="../susantaylor.htm">Susan Taylor</a></li>
      <li><a href="../LaboratoryMembers.html">Lab Members</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a href="../currentmembers.htm">Current Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="../formermembers.htm">Former Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="../gallery.htm">Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="../publications.htm">Publications</a></li>
      <li><a href="../links.htm">Links</a></li>
      <li><a href="../contact.htm">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>

  <br>
 </br>
<div id= "content" align="center"> 
<br>
<div id="content-spacer-top"> </div>
    <div id="content-inner"> <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" --  >EditRegion3<!-- TemplateEndEditable --></div>
   <div id="content-space bottom"></div>

</div>
<footer class="footer" id="footer">
  <div align="center">
  <p>Taylor Laboratory<br> 
      Leichtag Biomedical Research Building
      4th Floor, Room 412
    <br>
    University of California, San Diego
    <br>
    9500 Gilman Dr. mc0654<br>
  La Jolla, CA 92093
  <br>
  Ph: (858) 534-8190
  <br>
  Fax: (858) 534-8193 </p>
</div>
</footer>


</div>


</body>
```

CSS
    li ul{
    display:none;
    }

```
li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #357f7f;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
}
#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 1280px;
    min height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
 }
#content-spacer-top {
    height: 10px;
}

#content-spacer-bottom{
    height:1%;
}

#header {
    background-color: #357f7f;
    height: 2%;
    width: 100%;
}
#mainnav a  {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 14.28%;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: none;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 2%;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-left-width: thin;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-top-color: #357F7F;
    border-right-color: #357F7F;
    border-bottom-color: #357F7F;
    border-left-color: #357F7F;
}
#mainnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#mainnav a:hover,#mainnav a:active,#mainnav a:focus {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #357F7F;
}
.style2 {
font-size: small;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #357F7F;
}
.style4 {font-size: x-small}
.style5 {background-color: #357f7f; font-family: arial;}
#footer {
width:1280px;
height:120px;
float:left;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine from what you have explained in your question, could you go a little more in-depth?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/amchen/sqpe7ssp/

@jordan Sorry. I realize that the JS fiddle I posted previously doesn't accurately portray the problem I am facing. Hopefully the new link helps a little more. 
The overall navigation bar is horizontal, but the drop down menu should be vertical. Instead when I hover over "Lab Members" the drop down menu appears horizontal instead of vertical. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so after having a look at your updated fiddle I was able to see the problem straight away. Firstly your code is really messy (sorry, but it is haha) and you have so many unnecessary css declarations.

It was so badly written I have just written a brand new fiddle and included a working navigation bar. Find the relevant code below.

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
     <ul>
          <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="../research.html">Research</a></li>
          <li><a href="../susantaylor.html">Susan Taylor</a></li>
          <li><a href="../LaboratoryMembelrs.html">Lab Members</a>
              <ul>
                    <li><a href="../currentmembers.html">Current Members</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../formermembers.html">Former Members</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="../publications.html">Publications</a></li>
          <li><a href="../links.html">Links</a></li>
          <li><a href="../contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
    display: table;
    border-top: 1px solid #357F7F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #357F7F;
}
nav ul {
    display: table-row;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
nav ul a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #357F7F;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
nav ul ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    width: 100%; 
}
nav ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n65xkv8/)**

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hello Jordan. Thank you! I just started learning it on my own so it's definitely a work and progress. I'll remember to send you the link for the website once it's done so you can see it if you'd like. Thanks again~!

Comment: No problem, sorry if my original answer came across kind of harsh, that wasn't my intention. If you'd like any further help feel free to add me on Skype (comment back if so). You definitely want to be heading down the responsive road with your website though, so keep that in mind :)

Comment: I would definitely appreciate that. It is up already, but there are definitely some design problems I'd like to fix ( such as adding a drop down menu and picture gallery). It had been out of date for 5+ years until I took the time to update the whole site. Feel free to take a look. Any constructive criticism is welcome :) http://susantaylorlab.ucsd.edu/

Comment: I'm liking the simplicity of the design, there are just certain things that I would change personally, the typography being one of them. Typically it should be fully responsive too!